Discord.py bot 403 Forbidden (error code:50001): Missing Access when sending a message in a dm
I have given my bot the permissions that it should need in order to send a message in a dm however when using the slash command I get an error as soon as I try to send a message in the channel. I am, however, able to respond to the interaction in the channel.
If responding to the interaction is the only intended way to make these kinds of applications than some advice on how to listen for messages without using channel.history or channel.last_message which both lead to the same error code would be much appreciated
I have tried changing just about every Scope I could in the developer portal, I have tried alternative ways of sending/receiving messages mostly by using the interaction.response.send_message and interaction.response.followup but was unable to find some way of reading a message using only the interaction follow ups.
Here is some code that replicates my issue, the print statement (I believe) shows that the bot should have message sending privilege's in the dm.
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@discord.app_commands.allowed_installs(guilds=True, users=True)
@discord.app_commands.allowed_contexts(guilds=True, dms=True, private_channels=True)
@bot.tree.command(name="start",description="Start a game!")
async def Start(interaction:discord.Interaction, players: int=2):
    
    print(f"{interaction.channel.permissions_for(interaction.channel.me).send_messages=}")
    await interaction.response.send_message("Hello!")
    await interaction.channel.send("Hello 2!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online!")
    await bot.tree.sync()

bot.run(token)




The code you gave seems to work for me, maybe you just have Direct Messages closed?

@LiaMilenakos does the bot only say "Hello!" or does the bot say both "Hello!" and "Hello 2!"?

It does say both, yes.

Keep in mind that the bot doesn't need any permissions on the channel when it's responding to an interaction.
To send a regular message, your bot will need permission to send messages in the channel. A bot can send messages in a user's DM channel only if:

The bot shares a common server with the user;
The user has authorized direct messages to members of that server.

Certainly one of these conditions is not met for your user and that is why the bot gets the Forbidden error when sending messages.

I checked and even when sharing a server and with dms authorized it still returns missing access, for what it is worth does it matter that im using the bot's slash command in a dm? Is there different restrictions for application commands in dms as opposed to application commands in guilds?
